# Finding the dimension of V

Tags: linear-algebra

Studying for an exam and this question appeared on a previous exam.

Let $P_4$ be the space of all polynomials of degree at most 4. The subspace $V$ of $P_4$ consists of all polynomials $p(t)$ such that $p(0) = 2p(1)$. Dimension of $V$ is$\dots$

The answer is 4, but I'm not sure I understand. I fairly sure the dimension would be 5 if we were only considering $P_4$, but it seems $p(0) = 2p(1)$ is affecting it in some way. Any advice?

Comment: $p(0)=2p(1)$ is not true for all polynomials, so of we only consider the ones for which it is true, then clearly our space shrinks. Consider as a parallel the dimension of the space of all vectors $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \Bbb R^3$ such that $x_1=2x_2$. That's two-dimensional.

Comment: For *intuition*: $\dim(P_4)=5$ and $p(0)=2p(1)$ is $1$ linear constraint, so $\dim(V)=5-1=4$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have that

$$p(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$$

and

$$p(0)=2p(1)\implies e=2a+2b+2c+2d+2e \implies e=-2a-2b-2c-2d$$

that is

$$p(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx-2a-2b-2c-2d=\\=a(x^4-2)+b(x^3-2)+c(x^2-2)+d(x-2)$$

and the basis is $(x^4-2),(x^3-2),(x^2-2),(x-2)$, therefore the dimension is $4$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.

Comment: @mymemesarespiciest Well done, You are welcome! Bye

Comment: Another approach: define $T : P_4 \to K$ by $T(p) = p(0) - 2 p(1)$.  Then $T$ is a linear transformation.  Since $T$ is not identically zero, it's easy to see the image has dimension 1.  Now, use the rank-nullity theorem to find the dimension of $\ker(T)$ which is exactly the same thing as $V$.